# What is @$ variable in perl?

Tags: perl

Ex:

```
 foreach my $var (@$tp)  
      {  
        my $sql=$startsql1.$var.$endsql1;  
        print " SQL stamt \n $sql \n";  
        my $sel_stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);  
        $sel_stmt->execute() or warn $DBI::errstr;  
        my @result = $sel_stmt->fetchrow_array();  
        $sel_stmt->finish();  
        $tphash{$result[0]} = [ @result ];          
     }
```

- @tp is an array. It is not giving any output when i print $var.

Comment: `$tp` is reference to array so `@$tp` dereferences it and makes it an array.

Comment: There is no `@tp` array anywhere in this code.  Do you have `@tp` somewhere in your code and are trying to iterate over it in this loop?  If so, you accidentally typed `@$tp` where you meant `@tp`.  Make sure you put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of every Perl program you write.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`@$` in the context above is not a variable. It's a dereference.

`$tp` is a reference to an array. `@$tp` says "dereference and give me the values", it could also be written as `@{$tp}`.

E.g.:

```
my @array = ( 1, 2, 3 );
my $array_ref = \@array; 
print "REF: ", $array_ref,"\n";
print "VALUES: ", join " ", @$array_ref;
```

You can create an array reference without having an actual array by the square brackets:

```
my $array_ref = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
```

Comment: @DipitSethi you should validate the answer (check mark on the left).

Comment: hey, can you help me with this -> DBD::SQLAnywhere initialisation failed: DBD::SQLAnywhere->driver didn't return a handle, i am getting this while running my code. Another code with db connection. i have put query also for the same.